# Is it safe to delete the 100 MB System Reserved Partition on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have 100MB System Reserved Partition. I have other 3 partitions (making a total of 4 - max for a basic disk)

- 1 for Windows 8.1
- 1 for Ubuntu 12.04
- 1 common extended partition with 2 logical drives

I've read that it's Windows 7 that makes a 100 MB partition, and windows 8/8.1 needs 350 MB. So am I correct to assume that the System Reserved Partition is remnant from when I had Windows 7, a while back and has nothing to do with my windows 8 partition?
Is it safe to delete the partition altogether? Will I run into any problems?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest editing your question so that you break out directly unrelated question as another question.

Comment: **No; Its not safe.**

Comment: @mdpc, Thank you for the suggestion. I have removed it from here for now.

Comment: @Ramhound, Could you please elaborate? If windows 8 is really using the partition, shouldn't it be 350MB in size?

Comment: @ShashwatBlack why do you think it should be 350 MB?

Comment: @gronostaj I read it in multiple places. [Here's](http://goo.gl/Q8ilnQ) one. However I never questioned the validity of it. Is 100 MB partition for Windows 8.1 usual as well? So in that case the partition is actively being used?

Comment: Its usual only if the system was upgrade from Windows 7 to windows 8.0.  The partition contains relevant Windows 8 data just not all the data it normally does.  The simple answer covert the disk to GPT then you won't have a partition limit

Comment: I remember formatting Windows 7 partition completely and re-installing Windows 8 on that. Windows 8 to 8.1 was however, upgraded via store.

Comment: My only exploration is the. The 350MB partition is only created on UEFI systems if you actually deleted the existing partitions and then installed Windows 8.0

Comment: I don't think I have a UEFI system. It's plain old Bios I believe.
I didn't format all the drives during the installation. Just the one with windows 7 on it.

Comment: If `System Reserved` partition is set as `Active` and `System` (look in Disk Management), then it's currently being used, so DO NOT delete.

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss Thank you. That helps. [It is indeed set as `Active` and `System`](http://i.imgur.com/IpCWa1T.png). Would you mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it?